# JavaScript "If" Statement Regarding Checkbox Not Working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, checkbox

I have set up an "if" statement in JavaScript that is to check whether or not a checkbox is checked. However, it does not seem to be working. It refers to a checkbox within a form, and the ID for the checkbox is "t1." Please let me know if there is anything apparent that would make it not function properly! It is to be executed when a button on the page is clicked, which should work properly without the "if" statement around it.

The code is below:

```
var t1v = document.getElementById("t1")

if (t1v.checked) {
    document.getElementById("l1q1").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("1q1-1").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("l1q1-1").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("1q1-2").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("l1q1-2").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("1q1-3").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("l1q1-3").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("1q1-4").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("l1q1-4").style.display = "inline";
}
```

Comment: You need to use a change event handler if you want to change the display when the checkbox is checked/unchecked

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ly73xd57/1/

Comment: Edit the jsfiddle to recreate your problem... what you have given is insufficient for any solutions

Comment: Arun P Johny: Done, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need an event handler

Not sure where you are adding your "checked" condition.

It should be something like this

```js
function click1(){
  
   if($("#t1").is(":checked"))
   {
     alert("checked");
   }
  else{alert("not checked")}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="t1"/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click here" onclick="return click1();"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Do I need an event handler, though, if I don't want action to be performed immediately after the checkbox is checked? I want it to happen after a button is clicked, which has an "onclick" event.

Comment: No problem. Just save the value true or false in some variable or you can just access the value of checkbox using if($("#t1").is(':checked'))

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, you need to do it in a button click

```js
function t1Handler() {
  var t1v = document.getElementById("t1"),
    display = t1v.checked ? 'inline' : 'none';
  document.getElementById("l1q1").style.display = display;
  document.getElementById("1q1-1").style.display = display;
}

document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener('click', t1Handler, false);
```

```html
<input id="t1" type="checkbox" />
<span id="l1q1">l1q1</span>
<span id="1q1-1">1q1-1</span>

<button id="mybtn">Do it</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I have added to the code, but it's not quite working properly. I have updated the JSFiddle page, if you would be so kind as to take a look!

Comment: can you specify what should happen when the button is clicked

Comment: There should be radio buttons, etc. that show. But I got it working. Thanks so much for responding!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working! The problem seemed to be that I removed the checkbox element from the document before running the code to check whether or not it was checked. Tha